# Cypress: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-wait-util'

Tags: javascript, webpack, cypress

I'm using Cypress 7.5 and trying to use [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until).

What I did is:

1. Run `npm i -D cypress-wait-until`
2. Add `import 'cypress-wait-until';` to `cypress/support/commands/index.js` file

Now, I'm not able to run tests due to the following error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./cypress/support/commands/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-wait-util' in 'E:\project\cypress\support\commands'
resolve 'cypress-wait-util' in 'E:\project\cypress\support\commands'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: E:\project\package.json (relative path: ./cypress/support/commands)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    Looked for and couldn't find the file at the following paths:
[E:\project\cypress\support\commands\node_modules]
[E:\project\cypress\support\node_modules]
[E:\project\cypress\node_modules]
[E:\node_modules]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util.js]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util.json]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util.jsx]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util.mjs]
[E:\project\node_modules\cypress-wait-util.coffee]
 @ ./cypress/support/commands/index.js 3:0-28
 @ ./cypress/support/index.js
 
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\@cypress\webpack-preprocessor\dist\index.js:172:23)
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Watching._done (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:98:28)
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:499:39)
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:54:20
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:482:27
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
    at done (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:464:33
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:111:16
    at C:\Users\Dev\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\7.5.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:61:14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to specify the correct URL for the package installed inside `node_modules`. like:

```
import '../../../node_modules/cypress-wait-util';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dark mode then don't use it.....it can cause the issue
In My case, I was getting the same issue then I removed dark mode then

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

As per your error message- cy is looking for -resolving 'cypress-wait-util' in 'E:\project\cypress\support\commands' but you have added this under- E:\project\cypress\support\index.js'.
So I think - Adding this directly to your project's cypress/support/commands.js:
should work fine.